# Maintaining image aspect-ratio while absolutely positioning elements on top of image (tailwind aspect ratio plugin)

Tags: css, image, tailwind-css, css-position, tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

I am trying to position absolutely a tag on top of an image.
I am using the aspect ratio plugin to maintain the aspect-ratio of the image whatever the screen size https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

Here's my attempt to do it :
https://play.tailwindcss.com/Vfq5YRNMjM?file=config

As you can see the green tag is taking the all div space and not displaying properly.
If you remove the `aspect-w-5 aspect-h-2` from the wrapper div, it works fine though.

How can you maintain the aspect ratio of the image using the aspect-ratio tailwind plugin and position elements absolutely on top of the image at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

Solution 1:
We have just modified the structure for position relative and absolute elements.
Please refer to this link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/8naf2Yubny

Solution 2:
Add `left-auto bottom-auto w-auto h-auto` class to the green tag.
Please refer to this link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/yor1VczVcg